How can I mount a barrel bolt strike to a fiberglass entry door?
I would like to install this barrel bolt

on this fiberglass door, which is pretty standard, got it at Home Depot about 10 years ago.

My question is, will I have enough firm substrate in the door where the strike needs to go about 1/2" from the edge so that the screws bite securely and hold the strike in place? This is an optional/spare locking solution so it doesn't have to be super heavy duty.

Find out the door construction - you bought it so should be able to contact the manufacturer for the detail. We can only guess...

I don't have the documentation and all the labeling is washed off, i am depending on the crowd here to recognize what it may be made of and inside based on clues

Should think of them of an optional way to keep the door closed from blowing in the wind(replacing the latch type).  Pilot holes for the screws should show what the door is made of inside.  Probably wood with a fiberglass skin.

I would encourage a more appropriate solution. There's probably no need to make your nice entry look like a doghouse. What's your goal?

Is something wrong with your deadbolt?

@Huesmann no buy i will need to remove the part of the jamb where the strikers are to redo it, for a couple of days and would like to be able to keep the door closed during that time

@amphibient closed, or locked?

Almost any residential skinned hollow door has a wood frame, be it steel, fiberglass, or other. This might be only about an inch wide on the top, bottom, and hinge side, but the strike side will have more depth to support the latch area.
To confirm, pull either the latch or the deadbolt with its two screws. See what you see. There might simply be a steel sleeve around the bore, but there might be wood.
Pull the center hinge off just the door slab. Slowly drill a small additional hole between the hinge screw holes. See how far you get before you punch out the far side. Note the composition of the shavings.
